# In/for what intention the Angels declared peace on earth?

Tags: word-study, hermeneutical-approaches

When someone is dying how can we greet peace on them?
So many children were killed when Jesus was born, and many people went through lament/mourning. In that situation how the Angels declared peace on earth??? 
"Glory to God in the highest, and on earth peace among those with whom he is pleased!" (Luke 2:14)

Anyone like to help me here?

Comment: @CynthiaAvishegnath This is a word study question on a New Testament passage. Comments on questions like these are not the place to voice your beef on an unrelated issue.

Comment: So my comment {there are no "angels" in the Hebrew text of the Bible} got deleted. Does it mean that it is an admission that whatever written in the Christian scriptures have nothing to do with the Hebrew text of the Bible. And therefore, the absence/presence/meaning of any concept in the Hebrew text has no bearing on Christian scriptures ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Angels declared that to the shepherds,  and over the one who was born in a stable. Thus to meek people.  Shepherds don't order people to get murdered. It is the rulers of the world who do that.

> Isa 40:23 (NIV) "He brings princes to naught
>       and reduces the rulers of this world to nothing".
>
> Mat 5:5 (NIV) "Blessed are the meek for they are going to inherit the earth".

The meek are not going to inherit the world, but the earth, which means that they will be resurrected to walk on earth, while the (unrepentant) murderers, etc. etc. will not.

Comment: Genesis includes some examples of shepherds arranging murder. I also (sadly) have personally known counter examples. No profession no matter lowly or grandiose is exempt from breaking God's Law. Whether or not your conclusion about the meek is correct your supporting arguments here don't hold water.

Answer (score 2):

> Ro 8:7 Because the carnal mind [is] enmity against God: for it is not subject to the law of God, neither indeed can be.

From the beginning man has been at war with God by his carnal mind. The carnal mind is that instinctive nature that serves itself. When you decide things without asking God, you are deciding good and evil for yourself and usurping God's position. You are making yourself to be as God.

Christ declared peace between God and man. He made the peace possible through his death. His birth was a promise of his death.

At the end of his life he declared that the bread was a symbol of his body. But at his birth the symbol of eating his body was laying him in the manger with the grass:

> Ps 104:14  He causeth the grass to grow for the cattle [sheep].

The gift of myrrh was the oil for his dead body. The frankincense was a sweet savor like the burnt offering.

By the prophecy of the star of Jacob that Jesus was the Prince of peace, the wise men trough their dream knew that Herod was not the prince of peace and would continue in violence. If the baby was the prince of peace, Herod was not.

His gift of peace to us, the peace between God and man, is the peace that is beyond understanding:

> Php 4:7 And the peace of God, which passeth all understanding, shall keep your hearts and minds through Christ Jesus.

The world is the isolation ward where God has put people who think they are God.  Remember that instinctive carnal nature?  He also gave us a system where we reap what we sow, and gives us what we want which produces pain, suffering and death. Rom 1:18ff.

We cause the suffering in the world when our flesh declares us to be gods. We are a bunch of fake gods causing each other to suffer. He gives us peace in the midst of the suffering, so that we can teach others of the peace of God, before removing us from the asylum and giving us circumstantial peace as well.

Put off the old man, and put on the new. Joh 33:4-7

> 2Co 5:17 Therefore if any man [be] in Christ, [he is] a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new.

Accept the peace with heaven offered by Christ.

After Adam had sinned, God told him that he must eat bread by the sweat of his brow. Cain chose to live under the curse and offered God a gift from the curse. Abel chose not to live under the curse. He raised sheep and gave the first one back to God in hopes of replacing the one that was slain so he could return to the garden.

In the same way, we have the choice to continue to live at war with God, and under the curse, or we can look for that city not made with hands and be at peace through the Lamb of God.

Merry Christmas.

Comment: Good answer, Bob.  The peace toward men is the offer from God of Christ Jesus. It is not a declaration of peace between men, although that can be a side benefit for those who are in Christ.

Answer (score 0):

It was the because of  act of Good will by God towards men that the angels were celebrating. God had made a way of salvation through this child that was born.

Luke 2:10,11

> 10 And the angel said unto them, Fear not: for, behold, I bring you
>   good tidings of great joy, which shall be to all people.
>
> 11 For unto you is born this day in the city of David a Saviour, which
>   is Christ the Lord.

The angels brought these good tidings of peace, bringing great news of salvation.

Isaiah 52:7

> 7 How beautiful upon the mountains are the feet of him that bringeth
>   good tidings, that publisheth peace; that bringeth good tidings of
>   good, that publisheth salvation; that saith unto Zion, Thy God
>   reigneth!

Now men were going to have peace with God through Christ and that was good news for all people.

Romans 5:1

> 1 Therefore being justified by faith, we have peace with God through
>   our Lord Jesus Christ:
>   Yet this great awful peace that was to be given to men was to be at a cost. It was going to cost the saviour awful rejection, suffering and  death.
>   Yet the results were greater than the suffering.
>   Isaiah 53:5
>
> 5 But he was wounded for our transgressions, he was bruised for our
>   iniquities: the chastisement of our peace was upon him; and with his
>   stripes we are healed.

Isaiah 53:10-12

> 10 Yet it pleased the LORD to bruise him; he hath put him to grief:
>   when thou shalt make his soul an offering for sin, he shall see his
>   seed, he shall prolong his days, and the pleasure of the LORD shall
>   prosper in his hand.
>
> 11 He shall see of the travail of his soul, and shall be satisfied: by
>   his knowledge shall my righteous servant justify many; for he shall
>   bear their iniquities.
>
> 12 Therefore will I divide him a portion with the great, and he shall
>   divide the spoil with the strong; because he hath poured out his soul
>   unto death: and he was numbered with the transgressors; and he bare
>   the sin of many, and made intercession for the transgressors.

Through this child fellowship between God and man was going to be restored, the vision of Jacob's ladder was going to be made a reality. Through this child the gateway to heaven was going to be opened for men. Through this child men were going to have acess to the Holy of holies, the Shekinah glory. Through this child men were going to be restored back to God. That was good news of peace of greater significance and effect than his suffering.